# Проблема с Fancybox - после клика исчезает исходное изображение

Tags: html, jquery, css, fancybox, всплывающее-окно

Всем привет! У меня Проблема с Fancybox - после клика исчезает исходное изображение. притом обязательно нужно, чтобы fancybox срабатывал именно на img, а не на ссылке, т.к. картинки подгружаются динамически

демонстрация - http://jsfiddle.net/o3n4dcLs/

```
<img src="http://www.cruzo.net/user/images/k/prv/d760fbd8f50d9b92dc054ee8390df166_617.jpg" />
$("img").fancybox({
autoSize: false,
minWidth: 100,
minHeight: 100,
width: 100,
height: 100,
scrolling: 'yes'
```

});

Comment: а может объясните подробнее, почему динамическая подгрузка картинок мешает сделать ссылку в коде? плагин Fancybox так устроен, что у него есть img с изображением и есть ссылка с этого изображения, где хранится изображение для попапа, поэтому у вас не работает, а вот так работает: http://jsfiddle.net/MasterAlex/o3n4dcLs/1/

Comment: вот как вариант - http://jsfiddle.net/s1bj94ku/ - но лучше все таки использовать ссылкой

Comment: изображение выводятся в таком формате <? u_img(2103); ?> - как предлагаете добавить на них ссылки? (может вы подскажите, я не знаю как), притом картинок тысячи - и не особо хочется возиться с глобальными правками кода

Comment: @Вася, можно обернуть изображения в ссылку с помощью jQuery: `$('img').each(function() {
   $(this).wrap("<a href=" + $(this).attr('src') + "></a>"); 
});`

Answer (score 5):

Столкнулся с этой проблемой сегодня. Решение было простым:

Изначально HTML код был таким

```
<a href="" class="lightbox main-image thumbnail">
    <img src="http://ltcompany.com/media/cache/6f/16/6f163c0d308de8ede31922d0d765b467.jpg" alt="">
</a>
```

Как видите, атрибут href пустой. И после увеличения фото исходная картинка исчезала.

Всё решается добавлением адреса фото в href:

```
<a href="http://ltcompany.com/media/cache/6f/16/6f163c0d308de8ede31922d0d765b467.jpg" class="lightbox main-image thumbnail" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://ltcompany.com/media/cache/6f/16/6f163c0d308de8ede31922d0d765b467.jpg" alt="">
</a>
```

Comment: я это знаю - спасибо конечно за старания, но вы не внимательно прочитали условие "притом обязательно нужно, чтобы fancybox срабатывал именно на img, а не на ссылке, т.к. картинки подгружаются динамически" (ваш простой ответ работает только для статики) и ответ уже был дан  в комментариях выше